# Radius of curvature at given point

Tags: calculus, curvature

The value of radius of curvature for the curve $$s = ce^{x/c}$$ at $(s,\psi)$

I know that radius of curvature is $$ \frac{(1+y_1)^2}{y_2}$$ how to apply these formula here

Comment: What are $y_1$ and $y_2$?

Comment: First derivative and second derivative

Comment: Hint: Recall $\cos\psi=dx/ds$.

Answer (score 0):

Given $y=c e^{x/c}$ the curvature in cartesian coordinates is
$$\kappa(x)=\frac {|y''|}{\left(1+{y'}^{2}\right)^{\frac {3}{2}}}$$
So in this case
$$\kappa(x)=\frac{e^{x/c}}{\left| c\right|  \left(e^{\frac{2 x}{c}}+1\right)^{3/2}}$$
radius of curvature is
$r(x)=\frac{1}{\kappa(x)}$.

In this case
$$r(x)=\left| c\right|  e^{-\frac{x}{c}} \left(e^{\frac{2 x}{c}}+1\right)^{3/2}$$